# duplicity: problem parsing WebDAV URLs in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, url, duplicity

I am not a seasoned Ubuntu admin, so please bear with me if I am missing something obvious...

1. Many WebDAV-providers supply usernames as "emailaddress@provider.tld". Although this does not seem to be RFC-compliant, users have to live with that anyway...
2. Many WebDAV backends ignore duplicity's FTP_PASSWORD environment variable.
3. Duplicity works OK when providing cleartext password from CLI, e.g.

   ```
   duplicity /localdir webdavs://'emailaddress@provider.tld':cleartextpassword@webdavname.provider.tld/remotedir
   ```
4. However, I do not want to use my cleartext password in the command line process so that other users might not spoof it from the process list
5. Trying to use duplicity from a shell script (bash), without using the cleartext password in the command, e.g.

   ```
   PWVARIABLE='cleartextpassword'
   duplicity /localdir webdavs://'emailaddress@provider.tld':$PWVARIABLE@webdavname.provider.tld/remotedir
   ```

I always run into parsing problems of the juxtaposed "@" symbol which, together with the WebDAV URL, will be parsed into the variable name. This does not seem to be relieved by exchanging "%40" for "@" as duplicity (or bash?) do not seem to parse this in a useful manner.

Is there a workable syntax for this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quoting `$PWVARIABLE` will work (`duplicity /localdir webdavs://'emailaddress@provider.tld':"$PWVARIABLE"@webdavname.provider.tld/remotedir
`), but won't solve the problem of the password in the process list. Do you need to run this from a script?

Comment: Yes. I want to run it from a script which would be run by cron e.g. on a weekly basis for off-site backups.

Comment: Using @kos quotes around $PWVARIABLE does not work in my script. "$PWVARIABLE" does not seem to be parsed as a variable but as a text input. I get  the error message [...]Giving up after 5 attempts. ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 49

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered on launchpad by the very helpful duplicity dev team:

https://answers.launchpad.net/duplicity/+question/289684